# Plesk: libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient_r.so.16

Tags: linux, mysql, centos, innodb

I've found this error in my logs:

```
relocation error: /usr/lib64/libmyodbc5.so: symbol strmov, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient_r.so.16 with link time reference
```

*yum-error-log*

```
yum install mysqlclient16
...
184 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
Package mysqlclient16 is obsoleted by mysql-libs, trying to install mysql-libs-5.1.59-1.el6.art.x86_64 instead
Package matching mysql-libs-5.1.59-1.el6.art.x86_64 already installed. 
Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

i've used the atomicrepo using the latest mysql-version (mysql-5.1.59-1.el6.art.x86_64) on a server driven by **CentOS6**.

--

Plesk: This also appears in Plesk 10.3 > Application Vault as "Error 500"

--

edit: i've posted my solution as a response, maybe somebody will need it

Comment: Which MySQL version are you running?

Comment: And how did you install it?

Comment: i've updated the question, see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your mysql-packages seems to be destroyed or wrong configured (i aspect this happens only on centos6)

1. For now I may advise you to dump all databases like:

   ```
   # mysqldump -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` --all-databases > /root/mysql.full.dump
   ```
2. Then uninstall all MySQL related packages:

   ```
   # rpm -qa | grep mysql
   # rpm -e --nodeps `rpm -qa | grep mysql`
   ```
3. Disable the atomic-repo in /etc/yum.repos.d

   ```
   enabled = 0
   ```
4. Clean up yum:

   ```
   # yum clean all
   ```
5. Then use autoinstaller and install them:

   ```
   # /usr/local/psa/admin/bin/autoinstaller
   ...
   Next > Next > Next:

   11 [x] MySQL server support
   ```
6. Start MySQL-Daemon again

   ```
   # service mysqld start
   ```
7. After that you may restore your databases:

   ```
   # mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` < /root/mysql.full.dump
   ```

don't forget to re-enable the atomic-yum repository - Enjoy!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error which I had fixed by installing mysql-libs.

```
yum install mysql-libs
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem in Debian 6.0.4 with plesk

```
websrvmng: /opt/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng execution failed:
/usr/bin/sw-engine: relocation error: /usr/bin/sw-engine: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
websrvmng: /opt/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng execution failed:
/usr/bin/sw-engine: relocation error: /usr/bin/sw-engine: symbol __cxa_pure_virtual, version libmysqlclient_16 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.16 with link time reference
```

Fixed by installing libmysqlclient16

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient16
```